# In MariaDB/MySQL, how do I retrieve the same column from different records returned in a single row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested

I would like to retrieve a single row that shows the top three colors of products belonging to a specific set. The order is predefined and for some context, the way I would retrieve the top color is below. But I need to show the top three colors in three different fields but in a single row.

```
SELECT
   color
FROM
   product
WHERE
   category_id = 100
ORDER BY
   FIELD(p.color, 'Red','Orange','Blue','Yellow','Pink','Purple','Brown','Green','Clear','unknown','')
LIMIT 1
```

I'd like the effect of "LIMIT 3" at the end but I would need a single row, not three rows.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  From your description, `color` has only one value, so it is not clear what you mean by "top three colors in a single row".  And how do you define "top"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve 3 rows and combine the results with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(color)
FROM (
    SELECT
       DISTINCT color
    FROM
       product
    WHERE
       category_id = 100
    ORDER BY
       FIELD(p.color, 'Red','Orange','Blue','Yellow','Pink','Purple','Brown','Green','Clear','unknown','')
    LIMIT 3
) x
```

If you need them to be in separate columns in the result, you can put the subqueries in the `SELECT` list, with different `LIMIT` clauses.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT
       DISTINCT color
    FROM
       product
    WHERE
       category_id = 100
    ORDER BY
       FIELD(p.color, 'Red','Orange','Blue','Yellow','Pink','Purple','Brown','Green','Clear','unknown','')
    LIMIT 0, 1) AS first,
    SELECT
       DISTINCT color
    FROM
       product
    WHERE
       category_id = 100
    ORDER BY
       FIELD(p.color, 'Red','Orange','Blue','Yellow','Pink','Purple','Brown','Green','Clear','unknown','')
    LIMIT 1, 1) AS second,
    SELECT
       DISTINCT color
    FROM
       product
    WHERE
       category_id = 100
    ORDER BY
       FIELD(p.color, 'Red','Orange','Blue','Yellow','Pink','Purple','Brown','Green','Clear','unknown','')
    LIMIT 2, 1) AS third
```

Comment: This puts me on the right track, thank you! I'll need the subqueries in the FROM clause, not the SELECT but this is terrific.

Comment: How would you avoid getting 'Red' in the second and third columns if the event there are many reds? I'd want Red to appear only as 'first', regardless of how many times it's mentioned.

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT color`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(color ORDER BY cnt DESC) as colors
FROM (SELECT p.color, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM product p
      WHERE p.category_id = 100 AND
            p.color IN ('Red', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Yellow',' Pink', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Green', 'Clear', 'unknown', '')
      GROUP BY p.color
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) p;
```

If the colors appear once and `TOP` refers to the ordering, then use `GROUP_CONCAT(ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(color ORDER BY FIELD(p.color, 'Red', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Green', 'Clear', 'unknown', '')) as colors
FROM product
WHERE category_id = 100;
```

Comment: Why are you ordering by count instead of `FIELD(...)`?

Comment: Thank you for your response! The GROUP_CONCAT (which I had never heard of before today, so I thank you for that) returns the colors in a single field/column but I would need separate columns/fields for each color.

Comment: @Dave . . . In the second query, it is ordering by `FIELD()`.